# How to make evince "Send To..." work with Thunderbird in Xubuntu LTS?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunderbird, evince, preferences

I am currently working with the evince 3.10.3 document viewer on Xubuntu LTS 14.04.
When I hit `File > Send To...`, I receive the following error message from evince:

```
Could not send current document
Failed to execute child process "(null)" (No such file or directory)
```

Nevertheless, I have `Mozilla Thunderbird` defined as the `Mail Reader` in `Preferred Applications` under `Settings Manager`.

What else should I configure?

Comment: Yeah, I see the exact same behavior. Possibly a bug that should be reported on Launchpad.

Comment: The problem could also stem from the fact that evince forms part of the GNOME3 suite, using GTK3 and ignoring other desktop default program settings. XFCE4 is still GTK2.

Comment: Yup, that could well be it. I would actually suspect that Evince would ignore any non-Gnome3 settings, like freedesktop.org standards.

Answer (score 4):

Hitting *File* > *Send To ...* evince is looking for a `nautilus-sendto` executable. If not available the 'send to' command fails.

If you don't have or want or can install `nautilus-sendto` you can setup an alternative script to send documents to Thunderbird. Run this command:

```
sudo nano /opt/evince-send-to-thunderbird
```

In the `nano` text editor that appears in your terminal, add this text:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
thunderbird -compose "attachment='$1'"
```

Save the file and quit `nano`. (If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> you will have the opportunity to do both.) Then run these commands:

```bash
sudo chmod 775 /opt/evince-send-to-thunderbird
sudo ln -s /opt/evince-send-to-thunderbird /usr/bin/nautilus-sendto
```

*After a restart of evince*, the fake `nautilus-sendto` script is found on the path and the 'send-to' command opens a Thunderbird Compose window with the current document as an attachment.