# pdf reader with Send By Mail option

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

Is there any PDF reader which has a '**send by mail**' menu option that can attach the PDF to an email (preferably Thunderbird)?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve? Why don't you simply use the file manager context menu or the attachment actions of the mail user agent altogether? Why should a PDF reader know anything about e-mails?

Comment: I did not get your comment! If one is reading a Pdf document and want it to send to someone, it will be way easier to just have a menu item "send by email" which directly opens Thunderbird write window with Pdf already attached. Such option is available in libreoffice under File->Send->Document as email.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Whatever it sounds like, this question is not an XY problem because it's easy to 'send by mail' a pdf file in Ubuntu without installing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Evince on my Ubuntu 16.04 which gives me the ability to attach a PDF document to an email using Thunderbird.

You can download Evince from the Ubuntu Software Centre, if you don't have installed it already. It was already installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

[Official page of Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince)

If you installed Evince, open the document you want to send. Then go to `File` menu and then choose `Send To`. If Thunderbird is already installed, a `Create a new message` window will appear with the PDF document attached to it.

Check this screenshot:
 [image: Create a new message window]

Write your message and click on `Send` to send your message with that file as attachment.

Comment: Great! This works. However `nautilus-sendto` is also required for `Evince` `Send To`. This can be installed as `sudo apt-get install nautilus-sendto` or see https://askubuntu.com/questions/566053/how-to-make-evince-send-to-work-with-thunderbird-in-xubuntu-lts

Comment: I didn't know that! I use Ubuntu with Unity as Desktop Environment. That is installed by default, I guess. 
Do you use Xubuntu?

Comment: With Firefox (94) you may open a PDF with Thunderbird using the save button and choosing "open with" and than with "other program", scroll down and take Thunderbird. And the good thing is, that if you have done it once, it is rememberd as your choice.